Filter data from dataframe using each element of a list
I have a dataframe:
import pandas as pd

#Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'material_sub_category_id': [8038, 10063, 8038, 9539],
    'auction_id': [400, 401, 402, 403],
    'material_name': ['pig iron', 'sponge iron', 'pig iron' , 'billet'],
    'auc_rule': ['yankee', 'english no tie', 'yankee', 'english no tie'],
'h1_price': [27200, 24678, 27800, 34000]
})

I have created a list:
subcat_list = df['material_sub_category_id'].unique().tolist()
Gives the output [8038,
 10063,
 9627,
 9539]

Expected df: This I have done for 1 subcat
df_8038
material_sub_category_id | auction_id | material_name | auc_rule | h1_price
8038 400 'pig iron' 'yankee' 27200
8038 402 'pig iron' 'yankee' 27800

I am trying to filter out the dataframe for each 'material_sub_category_id' using a loop.

out = dict(list(df.groupby('material_sub_category_id')))

Thanks, I could create a list as well. listofdfs = [df.loc[df['material_sub_category_id']==val, :] for val in df['material_sub_category_id'].unique()]
listofdfs[0]
